# Copying output of command to windows clipboard

Tags: windows, ubuntu, clipboard

I'm working with an ubuntu 16.04 VPS which I log into through putty from windows. I want to copy the output of:

```
sudo nginx -T
```

to my windows clipboard. I've tried:

```
deploy@server:/etc/nginx/sites-available$ sudo nginx -T | xclip -selection c
Error: Can't open display: (null)
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

However nothing is copied to my local clipboard. How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass the $DISPLAY environment var to the command. Run it like this:

```
DISPLAY=:0 sudo nginx -T | xclip -selection c
```

if `xclip` doesnt work the you can also try using `xsel`